# Is there a way to automatically send major document versions to a Records Center while keeping the primary document active?

Tags: versioning, records-management

I'm working on a project in SP Server 2010 that requires strong record keeping. We have living documents that are constantly being updated, but we also have strict documentation requirements. Ideally, we would like to be able to work on and store our documents in a document library and send major versions of our documents elsewhere to be saved as records without having to declare the document itself as a record. I can't seem to configure the versioning or retention policies to make it happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a TimerJob, which copies the major versions of the documents to another document library every night or another interval.
Otherwise implement an SPItemEventReceiver, that also makes a copy when a major version of document is checked in. This could be done during the ItemCheckedIn event.

Comment: I've seen the first suggestion implemented which can copy the job over, even when using an SPD workflow, just have it wait for the correct status if there is an approval process for the documents.